# YouTube API Random Channel

Tags: youtube-data-api

Is there an easy way to select a YouTube Channel at random (ie. select a random channel ID)?

Or is there a database that supplies a current list of valid Channel IDs?

Comment: You can get all the channel IDs using the list function: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels - docs found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Comment: Thank you David Partyka.  However, the list requires me to add a filter to the query. Perhaps I can search through every categoryId, but is it true that every Channel is classified with at least one categoryId?